# Amount of stage by day given stage change dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which shows the date a person changes stages (a person can move from any stage to another):

| Name | Stage | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karen | One | 07/25/22 | $1 |
| Karen | Two | 07/27/22 | $1 |
| Jaren | One | 07/29/22 | $3 |
| Laren | One | 07/25/22 | $2 |
| Laren | Three | 07/28/22 | $2 |
| Laren | Two | 07/30/22 | $2 |

I would like to get a representation of which stage everyone was on every day.

| Stage | 07/25 | 07/26 | 07/27 | 07/28 | 07/29 | 07/30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | $3 | $3 | $2 | $0 | $3 | $3 |
| Two | $0 | $0 | $1 | $1 | $1 | $3 |
| Three | $0 | $0 | $0 | $2 | $2 | $0 |

You can see that both Karen and Laren were on stage 1 on 7/25 and this continued on 7/26 until Karen moved to stage 2 on 7/27.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking out - not new to SO, did not try any code because I couldn't figure out where to start. If I had, I would have made sure to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#Data preparation
string = """Name    Stage   Date    Amount
Karen   One 07/25/22    $1
Karen   Two 07/27/22    $1
Jaren   One 07/29/22    $3
Laren   One 07/25/22    $2
Laren   Three   07/28/22    $2
Laren   Two 07/30/22    $2"""
data = [x.split('   ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Filling miss dates
idx = pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max())
temp = df.groupby('Name')['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.DatetimeIndex(x).reindex(idx)[0].values).explode().to_frame().reset_index().merge(df, on=['Date', 'Name'], how='outer')

# Changing and pivoting

temp[['Stage', 'Amount']] = temp[['Stage', 'Amount']].ffill()
temp['Amount'] = temp['Amount'].str.replace('$', '').astype(float).ffill().fillna(0)
temp.pivot_table(index='Stage', columns='Date', values = 'Amount', aggfunc = 'sum', fill_value = 0, dropna = False)
```

Output:

```
Date    2022-07-25  2022-07-26  2022-07-27  2022-07-28  2022-07-29  2022-07-30
Stage                       
One 3   3   2   0   3   3
Three   0   0   0   2   2   0
Two 0   0   1   1   1   3
```

Comment: sorry, but i don't quite understand what is idx `reindex(idx)`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have int or float value in *amount* column

then you can use *groupby* and *pivot* to reshape dataframe

```
df.groupby(['stage', 'date'])['amount'].sum().reset_index().pivot(index='stage', columns='date', values='amount').reset_index().fillna(0)
```

> *df* is your original dataframe

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your answer with code explanations and improved formatting. It will help others understand.